# Monitor Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, tools

I was wondering if there is a free tool to monitor state of SQL Server 2000. I would prefer a web tool.

I would like to see if some database is accessible, or are there any problems on server, etc. Also I would like not to put to much extra load on SQL Server.

If anybody knows tool like this, please help

Thanks

Comment: this might be useful: http://www.zabbix.com/screenshots.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zabbix tool, posted in the comment, is not really working, because the server doesn't run on Windows, only the agent. See info in their [requirements page](http://www.zabbix.com/requirements.php). This means you'd need to install the tool on a Linux machine and only an agent on the Windows machine. Great if you have a heterogeneous environment, not really helpful in a full Win environment.

The same situation is for Nagios, another interesting open source monitoring tool. They say there is a package only for Windows, but the [doc page](http://www.nagios.org/news/77-news-announcements/273-introducing-nagwin-nagios-for-windows) it redirects to doesn't work now.

Of complete free monitoring tools useful for SQL 2000 I'm not really aware, but you can use successfully a pair of:

- Perfmon (find more info [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/))
- Server trace (trace specific queries, not just everything) -> actually files that can be open in SQL Profiler
- SQL Alerts (info in [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197962%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or here, in this [SimpleTalk article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-alerts-soup-to-nuts/))

PS: found that a great monitoring tool is also working on SQL 2000. So you'd better try to test [Confio Ignite free](http://www.ignitefree.com/sql-server/). It's fantastic for the price :-).

PS2: there is also a small free monitoring tool from Idera -> [SQL Check](http://www.idera.com/Free-Tools/sql-check/), but I don't know if it works on SQL 2000.

Comment: I would prefer a lightweight tool. From all tools you listed, what tool least put load on server?

Comment: None of them would put any big load on a system, except traces done with Profiler on the server itself. That's why I suggested server traces. The others shouldn't weigh too much. Anyway, you can use Perfmon, Ignite or SQL Check from another machine, so the database server itself remains mostly untouched. You might wanna find out that there's no free lunch out there, each tool has its cost (in learning, load, configuration, space..etc). That cost you'll find out after you'll do your own assessments.